# How to figure out what error my Java Eclipse project has?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've created a Java project from existing source with an Ant build script in Eclipse. I cannot run my project because Eclipse tells me that there is at least one error in it.

Now, I know that the project runs fine on the command line, so I suspect an Eclipse configuration error.

As far as I can tell, the only feedback that I have from Eclipse is

1. a little red X on my project in the Package Explorer window
   [image: Eclipse Error Package Explorer]
   <sub>(source: [gregmattes.com](http://gregmattes.com/EclipseErrorPackageExplorer.png))</sub>
2. and dialog window when I try to run the project says there are errors in the project
   [image: Eclipse Error Dialog]
   <sub>(source: [gregmattes.com](http://gregmattes.com/EclipseErrorDialog.png))</sub>

This is all wonderful, but ***what is the error?***

Is there a "show me the next error" button somewhere?

In the past, on other Eclipse projects, I've notice other little red X's on folders containing source files with errors, the little red X's appear on the source files as well. I scanned (manually) through all of the source files and I haven't found any other red X's (again, where is the "next error" button?).

If I select the "Proceed" button I am greeted with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for my main class, which makes me suspect a classpath issue. I've checked the classpath, and I'm fairly certain that it's correct. Is there a way to see the *exact* jvm command line that Eclipse is invoking? I realize that it might be invoking the JVM programmatically, and not on a "real" command line. In any case, is there a way, other than the run configuration dialog, to see what is *actually happening* when I hit the "Proceed" button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Eclipse, what can cause Package Explorer "red-x" error-icon when all Java sources compile without errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225167/in-eclipse-what-can-cause-package-explorer-red-x-error-icon-when-all-java-sou)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The errors are shown in the `Problems` view. If it is not opened, go to:

`Window > Show View > Problems`

[image]

Also accessible with the keyboard shortcut `Alt+Shift+Q,X`

Comment: Markers in Eclipse Kepler

Answer (score 7):

Selecing `Window -> Show View -> Problems` will open the Problems view, that should have a list of all problems, their location and nature (it can be configured to show only project- or file-local problems, so you may also have to click on the project). Most likely you have a config error in your project, e.g. a reference to a JAR library that cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

[View Errors/Warnings Project based](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/06/14/eclipse-problems-view-only-show-problems-for-project/)

[image: Show Errors/Warnings per Project]

Answer (score 0):

if you get that kind of an error which shows a red cross on the project folder just refresh that project right clicking on it i was having the same problem as above so try and see...