# Errors in Eclipse for no reason

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm building an Android app.

I worked today on my app, and suddenly I saw that all the projects in the workspace are marked with an error. I don't know what caused it, and I can't find explanation of the error anywhere.

I'm using Helios with Windows 7. I even tried downloading Eclipse again but it didn't help.

Today I tried to integrate Facebook with my app. Their tutorial required me to try to get a hesh key from a keystore. In the process I added an Environment Variable named JAVA_HOME, and pointed it to the JDK.

I don't know if it's the cause of my problem, but I think it might be related.

I really don't know what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Considered telling us what the error is?

Comment: You should tell us the error, or have this closed.

Comment: Does the view "Problems" indicated any error messages? ..or can you identify messages when viewing the property of the project. Without error messages everything is speculation.

Comment: I don't know what the error is, I can't see any description of it anywhere.EDIT - I do see the error in "Problems"(Thanks!) - java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

Comment: how did you know you got errors then? there should be something indicative of errors occurred.

Answer (score 9):

Try this. In eclipse, go to Project --> Clean --> Select "clean all projects". This should rebuild all projects.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your android project. I get problems with Eclipse sometime, and if I clean the project, it fixes it.

Comment: Project -> Clean... -> (Clean projects selected below) -> (Select project) -> OK

Answer (score 1):

Find the "Problems" view.  That will give you more details. Post the description of the problems, we can get more information.

click Window -> Show View -> Problems

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the problem is with a resource you've recently added to your project (drawable, assets, raw, etc.)

Some things to check are:

- Invalid XML files
- Invalid 9-patch images (outer 1-pixel border must be full black or transparent)

Typically, just start by removing a resource, then cleaning your project (Project > Clean). If the errors go away, that resource is your problem. If not, continue this process until the error DOES go away. Start with the most recent resources you've added, naturally.

Comment: I found the error - 

java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

Now i'm stuck trying to solve it.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: I tried cleaning the project, but the error tells the resources aren't the problem. The problem even pops in any completely new projects I create.

Comment: I'm telling you, this happens all the time to me. The resources are almost certainly the problem. It will cause Eclipse to fail to compile if it encounters a single problem in your resources, and the majority of the time, it won't be able to tell you which. At least give it a try. Another resource problem to watch for is XML files with uppercase letters.

Comment: I know what you are talking about, but this is isn't the case...How can you explain it that every new project I create is marked with this error, without me adding anything to it? It doesn't make sense

Comment: I can't explain it, but I know it's happened to me, that's all I can tell you. If that's not the case, I'm not sure what to try, I just know that every time this has occured, it's been due to a resource file.

Comment: You had the same problem with the same error about the key fault?

Comment: Never checked the Problems view, so I couldn't tell you, but it does cause all open projects to show build errors, and most (if not all) files within the projects to show build errors. It's at least worth a try, no?

Comment: Good luck! :) If not, this might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225167/in-eclipse-what-can-cause-package-explorer-red-x-error-icon-when-all-java-sour

Answer (score 1):

i solved error or all project showing errors this way.... close eclipse.
then Right Click on eclipse shortcut-->open file location-->open command widows there and type "eclipse.exe -clean" eclipse the starts..and in my case errors were gone...hope it helps