# How do you check this unknown error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

What kind of error is this? I tried to clean/restart the project, but it the red x still appears. How do you check this unknown error?
[image]

Comment: Right click project + Build Path + Configure build path --> now you can see the meaning of the red marks.

Comment: @NicholasK are you sure? Nothing wrong with the configuration

Comment: Try a clean build of your project.

Comment: in the location where you have console , you can also see errors tab , which can explicitly tell that why there is an error. Then you can post the error and we can figure out the solution

Comment: @NicholasK I did all of that, is there a manual way to see where the error belongs to?

Comment: Nothing appears at the console @Shubham

Comment: Try opening the Problems tab, check if anything is mentioned there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Eclipse, what can cause Package Explorer "red-x" error-icon when all Java sources compile without errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225167/in-eclipse-what-can-cause-package-explorer-red-x-error-icon-when-all-java-sou)

Answer (score 2):

you can have a look at this in your eclipse..
As you can see i also have some errors.
this would give you some idea as what the problem is.
[image]

something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the dependencies resolved , and no compilation errors.

In my case , maven->update projects->force update of snapshots/releases, 
then project->clean worked.